# How do I connect rds with elastic beanstalk in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I have the code to create the elastic beanstalk with terraform and here is the code I found in terraform docs to create an rds instance

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  db_name              = "mydb"
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.7"
  instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "foobarbaz"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"
  skip_final_snapshot  = true
}
```

The problem is that I can't find an example of how to connect this db to elastic beanstalk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `setting` option should be the way to go here, i.e., you probably do not need a separate resource for creating the DB. Based on the AWS docs [1], and using the terraform examples [2], it should be something like:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "tftest" {
  name        = "tf-test-name"
  description = "tf-test-desc"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "tfenvtest" {
  name                = "tf-test-name"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.tftest.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.3 running Go 1.4"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBAllocatedStorage"
    value     = "10"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBDeletionPolicy"
    value     = "Delete"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "HasCoupledDatabase"
    value     = "true"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBEngine"
    value     = "mysql"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBEngineVersion"
    value     = "5.7"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBInstanceClass"
    value     = "db.t3.micro"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBPassword"
    value     = "foobarbaz"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBUser"
    value     = "foo"
  }
}
```

However, I am not sure if the `parameter_group_name` can be set here.

EDIT: Answer updated to create a DB instance with the ElasticBeanstalk environment. However, make sure to understand this part about `HasCoupledDatabase` setting from the docs:

> Note: If you toggle this value back to `true` after decoupling the previous database, Elastic Beanstalk creates a new database with the previous database option settings. **However, to maintain the security of your environment, it doesn't retain the existing DBUser and DBPassword settings. You need to specify DBUser and DBPassword again**.

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-rdsdbinstance

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_environment#option-settings

Comment: So thus terraform will create an rds instance with given settings right?

Comment: As far as I understand the documentation, yes. :)

Comment: There might be an error because one of the settings works in conjunction with another one, so let me know if it doesn't work and I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: 'terraform apply' completed successfully but I checked rds and I didn't see a new db created.

Comment: Ah, yes, so it's the missing option. Do you want your environment to have the DB coupled or not? If yes, I can update the answer with that option. If not you can try with a separate terraform resource for the DB and then I can update the answer with a separate resource.

Comment: Yes sir, I think coupling is what I need.

Comment: Edited the answer, it has the required option now.